# How to remove newline characters from a String?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to remove newline characters from a `String` (file content read from a file) and convert it to a `Vec<u8>`.

Example input string:

```
let ss = String::from("AAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBB\nCCCCCC\nDDDDD\n\n");
```

```rust
fn parse(s: String) -> Vec<u8> {
    let s = s.chars().skip_while(|c| *c == '\n');
    let sett = s.into_iter().map(|c| c as u8).collect();
    sett
}
```

While I get no error, `skip_while` doesn't seem to remove the newline characters from the string. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can basically replace the `\n` from the string then convert it to `Vec<u8>` with [into_bytes()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes)

```rust
fn parse(s: String) -> Vec<u8> {
    s.replace("\n", "").into_bytes()
}
```

---

If you want to do it with iterators you can do it with filter:

```rust
fn parse(s: String) -> Vec<u8> {
    s.chars().filter(|c| *c != '\n').map(|c| c as u8).collect()
}
```

You can call it like following:

```rust
use std::str::from_utf8;

fn main() {
    let my_string = String::from("AAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBB\nCCCCCC\nDDDDD\n\n");
    let parsed_string = parse(my_string.clone());
    println!("{:?}", from_utf8(&parsed_string));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4643e1bee2986ccd31068a1685033ee9)

Comment: cast a char to a u8 is not a good thing to do use `bytes()` directly in this case.

Comment: You had your condition wrong. But even you correct it, It is not the behavior you asked. It skips until the first occurence and the string you get is only the first part skipped until the /n occurs. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d616c66b1a6b4c07514765d847f8437)

Comment: @RussellB: `take` and `skip` are common in functional languages for list operations: `take` will return a prefix list, and `skip` will return a suffix. There are variants build upon them: take/skip a number of elements, and take/skip while a predicate is true or until it becomes true. `skip_while` inherits this tradition, and therefore skip elements as long as the predicate is true, then returns whatever is remaining. In your case, since the predicate is false on the first element, it immediately stops skipping and returns the whole list.